# OpenShift - Unable to connect Strimzi from KafkaJS

Tags: node.js, apache-kafka, openshift, strimzi, kafkajs

I have Strimzi Kafka cluster set-up successfully on OpenShift. I can see the following services:

- `kafka-brokers`
- `kafka-bootstrap`
- `zookeeper-client`
- `zookeeper-nodes`

This is actually different from what is called out [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56083914/919480); so, not sure, if this is a Strimzi installation issue. I followed installation steps from [here](https://strimzi.io/quickstarts/okd/).

I created a routes for `kafka-bootstrap` and `kafka-brokers` on port `9092` (non-TLS clients). In both cases, I get a `ECONNREFUSED` error when I provide the route value (e.g. `my-cluster-myproject.192.168.99.100.nip.io:9092` in the example from [kafkajs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/kafkajs).

How do I get the `kafkajs` package connected to the Strimzi cluster?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Strimzi services that you are seeing are correct but in order to access the Kafka brokers, it's better using the bootstrap service which allows to specify only one "broker" in the bootstrap servers list of your client and it will select a broker to connect the first time and then getting metadata (it avoids to you to connect using the headless service where the pod IPs can change on restart).
So saying that, if you need to access the brokers from outside of OpenShift you don't have to create a route for the bootstrap service manually but you have to configure external listeners (https://strimzi.io/docs/latest/#assembly-configuring-kafka-broker-listeners-deployment-configuration-kafka) with type `route`.
As already mentioned above, the OpenShift routes work with TLS only for TCP connections.
In order to provide your clients the right certificate tu use for TLS you can follow this part of the documentation: https://strimzi.io/docs/latest/#kafka_client_connections

Comment: Following up this discussion here - https://stackoverflow.com/q/58245089/919480

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked out [external listeners](https://strimzi.io/docs/latest/#assembly-kafka-broker-external-listeners-deployment-configuration-kafka)?

BTW, if you need to expose strimzi by router, TLS encryption is necessary. OpenShift router does not support TCP, but support TLS.